# MVC models to populate KendoUI Multiselect - preloading selected items

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I currently have the multiselect working the way I want it with one exception.  Preloading previously selected items.

My view looks:

```
<div class="editor-field">       
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UntaggedPersons)
    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.PeopleToTag, 
             new SelectList(Model.CommitteeMembers, "PersonId", "FullName"))                
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#PeopleToTag").kendoMultiSelect({ "dataTextField": "FullName", "dataValueField": "PersonId", "placeholder": "Tag or Untag Persons to Action Item" });
```

PeopleToTag is an IEnumerable`<int>` int that posts to the controller
CommitteeMembers consists of a persons  First, Last, FullName, and PersonId

This works perfectly, I can manipulate who is tagged in the post to the controller.

Now I want to add the functionality of preselecting those that are currently tagged.

How do I add a preselected Value?  I have a model with:

model.TaggedPersons consists of a persons First, Last, Fullname, PersonId.

How do I wire up the javascript to display the model.TaggedPersons as the already selected value?

I don't mind using the MVC wrapper approach if it is easier.

I've tried something like:

```
<div class="editor-field">       
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TaggedPersons)
   @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(model => model.PeopleToTag)
     .Name("PeopleToTag")
     .Placeholder("These people are Tagged")
     .DataTextField("FullName")
     .DataValueField("PersonId")
     .BindTo(Model.CommitteeMembers)
     .Value(Model.TaggedPersons)          
    )
</div>
```

However this isn't even rendering a kendo multiselect for me at present. That's the general thought of how I want to approach it though.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Change:
DataTextField("FullName") to DataTextField("Text")

DataValueField("PersonId") to DataValueField("Value")

SelectList uses "Text" and "Value", respectively.  You already filled the fields of the select list with FullName and PersonId when the selectlist was created.